# How to not show insert mode mapping clue without touching the timeout

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I have some commands like `imap jk <Esc>`.

How can I manage to not display the visual cue when I start typing `j` (where the cursor actually waits before inserting) it keep messing up with my brain when I happen to use the j key

I don't want to change the timeout, I just want no visual indication that its waiting to see which other key I'm going to press.

Comment: What visual cue? The cursor staying on the `j`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EasyEscape** plugin does what you want:

https://github.com/zhou13/vim-easyescape/

You don't need to install Python3 if you accept a 2 seconds timeout.

Comment: this is perfect, how can we make this work on visual mode too ?

Comment: @user6714088 according to the plugin author, this is a known limitation: "Does not work in command/visual mode due to lack of InsertCharPre in vim/nvim." See the "Known problems" section in the link above.